# Android Screen Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, android-screen-support

I have uploaded an application to Google Play Store which I made compatible only with High Resolution screens.  I use the following code in Manifest.xml file to make the App compatible with High resolution screens only

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />     
<!-- large screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
```

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"
                       />
```

When i search my application on Google Play from browser  I am able to view the application details, but shows not compatible with the device. Also, when I search from the device, the application seems to be not available / No results found.  Can anyone please suggest me what all modifications I need to make in the Manifest file, so that I will be able to download the application?

**Note :** I have tried with Samsung Galaxy S, Galaxy Duos and Sony Xperia J.

Thanks in Advance,

Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:largeScreens="true"` tends to Tablet with size of 7", So if you search your application through a 7" Tablet then you able to see.

your `<compatible-screens>` tag seems ok, I guess you don't need to use `support-screen>` see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Comment: Thanks.. So if I remove this block of code from manifest file, then i will be able to download the application in High resolution phones?

Comment: I removed <supports-screens> Tag and its working fine now.. :)